# Javascript is submitting a simple request but not getting proper feedback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have the following setup where Javascript sends an AJAX request and it gets executed fine. The problem is that the AJAX submission is not getting the reply from server to display in the UI. `console.log(msg)` works but all the rest does not behave at all. How can I make sure every single output from PHP is received in Javascript?

ajax.php:

```
<?php
    $cmd = $_POST['command'];
    echo shell_exec("/usr/local/software/bin/cli -x '{$cmd}'");
?>
```

javascript.php:

```
$.post('ajax.php', {
    action: 'FEEDBACK-PLEASE?????',
    command: 'show status'
}, function(msg) {
    console.log(msg); // shows data arrived
    // following does not show the msg at all
    $('#terminal_output').html(msg); 
    alert('HELLO!!!!!! HELLO!! where is my feedback!! why you no alert???');
}, 'json');
```

**EDIT:** XHR body has data

[image]

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No console errors. In the console i can get the output from linux but same `$('#terminal_output').html(msg);  and alert` never executed

Comment: any data in the xhr body?

Comment: why do you have json in there, btw read up on command injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not returning json from your post request remove the json property

```
$.post('ajax.php', {
    action: 'FEEDBACK-PLEASE?????',
    command: 'show status'
}, function(msg) {
    console.log(msg); // shows data arrived
    // following does not show the msg at all
    $('#terminal_output').html(msg); 
});
```